# is "burial of optical fibers" correct?

Tags: expressions, internet

Would you say:

> The earliest stage of network design is the burial of optical fibers.

To say that the first stage, when you design an optical network, is to put the fibers under the ground ?

Comment: I’d say that step is ***far*** from the first step. But grammatically it’s fine.

Comment: That doesn't seem like a *design* step at all -- it's a step in the construction process.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Requests for proofreading or for writing advice are explicitly off-topic unless you can point to a specific point of grammar or usage that confuses you— why *wouldn't* it be correct; what rule or standard do you think it might violate? I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance. Our sister site for [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) may also be of interest.

Comment: I was confused by the usage of the word "burial" for something which has nothing to do with religion. I'm afraid you're right. I should have posted this question to ELL. Sorry. Should I delete the post ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Burial** is:

> the act *or* ceremony of burying [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/burial)

And burying is:

> to put in the ground and cover with earth [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/bury)

Which is what they're doing, so it's fine. The confusion probably arose from the second definition,

> to put (a corpse) in the ground or a vault, or into the sea, often with ceremony

But people should know what you mean when you bury cables.